# Creating a BSOD with assembly in protected mode

Tags: assembly, masm32, bsod

I was looking and couldn't find any quick and easy way to BSOD a computer in assembly. I'm using MASM x86. I'm new at assembly and want to make a version or Russian roulette for computers. Basically you keep hitting enter and if you lose your computer gets a blue screen of death. Its just for fun with a few friends. I would imagine its possible because there were a few post that said you could do this in C by ending a certain process in windows (crss.exe i believe). I figured since assembly is a lower level it could be done as well.

Comment: It seems like your question isn't getting much attention; perhaps if you could provide more detail on what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far it would be easier for people to help.

Comment: If your protect mode OS is performing properly, you shouldn't be able to BSoD it.  :-)  Therefore, you're attempting to exploit a flaw in the system, and those are shifting targets.  Not a good candidate for a solid StackOverflow question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

BSOD is a result of an error in Kernel mode. Tools that you use to create that error do not matter, it can be assembly, C or any other language that exists in Windows Kernel. In user mode there is no direct way to create a BSOD, independent of the language used. Like mentioned in the comments - user mode code can trigger BSOD only in case of exploiting a flaw in the system, allowing breach into the Kernel space.